# Редактирование файлов для чтения Visual Studio Code

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio-code

Мне понадобилось изменить KeyCode Unity, но Студия ругается, что файл только для чтения. Можно ли как-то редактировать файл?

Comment: ПКМ по файлу > Свойства > Убрать галочку с атрибута "Только для чтения"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не представляю зачем, но если очень хочется, то можно сделать следующим образом.

1. Создать файл KeyCode.cs в unity (в папке с Assets/Scripts )
2. Скопировать туда целиком содержимое файла из метаданных
3. Изменить namespace на свой, например:

   `namespace MyCustomKeyCode`
4. Соответственно, что бы его использовать надо будет в cs файлах добавлять

   `using MyCustomKeyCode`
5. Скорей всего захочется уметь превращать enum из Unity в ваш и наоборот, для этого можно добавить пару Extension методов: можно в KeyCode.cs, можно отдельно.

```cs
public static class KeyCodeExtensions
{
    public static UnityEngine.KeyCode ToUnityEngineCode(this MyCustomKeyCode.KeyCode input)
    {
        return (UnityEngine.KeyCode)input; //умная логика преобразования здесь
    }

    public static MyCustomKeyCode.KeyCode ToMyCustomCode(this UnityEngine.KeyCode input)
    {
        return (MyCustomKeyCode.KeyCode)input; //умная логика преобразования здесь
    }

}
```

Готово. Можете делать, что хотели. В коде это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
if (Input.GetKey(MyCustomKeyCode.KeyCode.UpArrow.ToUnityEngineCode()))
{
    Debug.Log("Hello World"); //Сообщение будет выведено при нажатии стрелочки вверх
}
```